# Python: more readable list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, string-algorithm

I am new to Python. I have the following code which is a part of a string algorithm that i'm currently developing.

```
>>> newlist=[]
>>> i =0

>>> for x in range(len(list1)):
       new_item = [y for y in list1[i] if y not in list2[i]]
       newlist.append(new_item)
       i=i+1

>>> print newlist
```

I like to do this using list comprehension as I've read it is performance optimized. Can somebody suggest me a method.

Thank you.

[Edit]

example:

```
list1= [[['pat'],['cut'],['rat']],  [['sat','pat'],['cut','pat']],[['instructor','plb','error0992'],['instruction','address','00x0993'],['data','address','017x112']]

list2= [[['pat'], ['cut'], ['rat']], [['sat', 'pat']], [['instructor', 'plb', 'error0992'], ['instruction', 'address', '00x0993']]]
```

So the new list,

```
newlist= [[], [['cut', 'pat']], [['data', 'address', '017x112']]]
```

Comment: can you give us a before and after example of what you're expecting from the input and outputs? Just so I can see the end goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want all elements that are in one list and not in another, I would suggest looking into python `set`s. They don't allow for duplicates, but the performance and readability benefits are large.

You would implement this like so:

```
newlist = list(set(list1).difference(set(list2)))
```

If you want to apply this in place of your current solutions, you should do something along the lines of what Dominic suggested (slightly edited for readability):

```
[list(set(a)-set(b)) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

If the order matters, or you have duplicates, then the single list comprehension you had above should do the trick, just wrap it as a lambda function to make it more readable:

```
single_item = lambda i: [y for y in list1[i] if y not in list2[i]]
newlist = [single_item(i) for i in enumerate(list1)]
```

Comment: You should do something like `[list(set(a)-set(b)) for (a, b) in zip(list1, list2)]` since `list1` and `list2` are list of lists.

Comment: I have edited the question. This implementation looks good. I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nested list comprehension that does the same thing as your code (albeit will not preserve the value of `i`).

```
newlist = [[y for y in list1[i] if y not in list2[i]] for i in range(len(list1))]
```

Comment: I did not think the poster particularly wanted the solution to be extremely readable. Sorry if that causes misunderstanding.

Comment: I interpreted "more readable list comprehension" as "put the code in list comprehension format because list comprehensions are generally easier to read." Again, I am sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: I've never really had a problem reading nested comprehensions.  I think it depends on the nested comprehension and the audience you writing for.

Comment: @icedtrees I like your implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** `[[y for y in list1[i] if j not in list2[i]] for i in enumerate(list1)]`

You should use `enumerate` instead of the `range(len())` non-idiom.  You may also want to consider making this a generator expression. Either with a concrete nested list:

`([y for y in list1[i] if j not in list2[i]] for i in enumerate(list1))`

or not

`((y for y in list1[i] if j not in list2[i]) for i in enumerate(list1))`